# Data structure to store the nodes of a DFA

Tags: c++, data-structures, dfa

I need a data structure to store the nodes of a finite deterministic automaton so that finding nodes which satisfy a particular condition is fast (logarithmic). 
The condition in question is the following:

> I have a node `p`, and I have to find a node `q`, such that: `(p ∈ F ≡ q ∈ F) & (∀ a : a ∈ Σ : δ(p,a) = δ(q,a))`. That is, `p` and `q` are either both final or both are not, and they have transitions to the same nodes.

I don't want to go through all the nodes because that would be slow. Obviously, if the set of alphabet characters, for which `q` has transitions, is different from the set, for which `p` has transitions, `q` isn't the node I'm looking for.

Furthermore, if `p` and `q` have a different number of transitions, `q` is again not the node I want. So I was thinking of a data structure that sorts the nodes according to their finality and number of transitions, so I don't have to look through all the nodes, just those which have the same finality and the same number of transitions. But that is still not logarithmic. Any ideas.

I'm using c++.

Comment: you wants to compare you dfa's, whether produce same language or not **?**

Comment: No, I'm incrementally constructing a minimal acyclic DFA.

Comment: ok you are working with single DFA,

Comment: @user763852 Regarding your comment: From the definition in your question I take it that you use the general minimization algorithm for DFAs, i.e. a minimization algorithm that works for DFAs with cycles as well. Since yours is acyclic, there are specialized minimization algorithms that can be implemented with less memory consumption. I don't recall any off the top of my head, but that's something you should probably look into as well.

Comment: This set of slides covers some of the "layer-wise" algorithms for acyclic-DFA minimization: http://www.stringology.org/event/2011/psc11p12_presentation.pdf

Comment: No, I'm not using the general minimization algorithm, I use the algorithm for the incremental construction of a minimal acyclic DFA explained here: [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167642303000121). If used the general algorithm then, to find an equivalent node, I would have to check the condition recursively for every node `q` points to. And I don't have to worry about rebuilding the hash, because I keep a subset of the nodes minimal, so those nodes' transitions don't change once added to this subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I constructed a string for each node and I put the strings in an AVL tree. It executed faster than the solution with the hash function and the unordered map and used far less memory.

The string representing the node looks as follows: it starts with a `0` or `1`, according to whether the node is final or not, and then the pairs `(a,n)` are coded as follows: `a` is an `int` corresponding to the position of the symbol `a` in the alphabet and `n` is another `int`, the index of the node it has transition to with the symbol `a`.

Comment: Seems you already have you you wanted. But in case you need more speed up, it can be worthwhile to look for BDDs (binary decision diagrams). BDDs are a very fast way to store logical formulas, but they can also be used to store finite state machines - you will find some info on the web

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of information at a node `q`:

- The boolean information `(q ∈ F)`
- The list of pairs `(a,n)` such that δ(q,a)==n (i.e. the list of character/dest-node pairs reachable from q)

These two pieces of information (a boolean and a list of pairs) can be represented as a single sequence, and you can compute a hash key for this sequence.

This will enable to hash the nodes by the property you are interested in. Searching for candidate nodes `q` for a given node `p` will then be near O(1).

(For the minimization algorithm you mentioned in the comments this means you'll need to rebuild this hash after each iteration, because the destination node pointers in the pairs will change as a result of the actions performed during the iteration.)

Comment: I've done that. I created a string  representing the information and I used the djb2 hash function, but for large dictionaries (containing around 4 000 000 words that the automaton is supposed to accept) I ran out of memory.

Comment: How did you represent the destination nodes in the `(a,n)` pairs when you transformed them into a string? You should represent them an `int` or `node*` and make the hash function process them as that, rather than serializing them to the string. You can also try putting only `node*` in the hash, rather than copies of the entire strings, or copies of the complete nodes. Also, you should check how many hash tables you keep in memory (if you run several iterations of the minimization, you may build a new table in each iteration and keep copies of the previous ones..?)

Comment: The string representing the information looks as follows: it starts with a `0` or `1`, according to whether the node is final or not, and then the pairs `(a,n)` are coded as follows `a` is an `int` corresponding to the position of the symbol `a` in the alphabet and `n` is another `int`, the index of the node it has transition to with the symbol `a`. Then, I use an `unordered_map<unsigned long,node*>`, where `unsigned long` is the value returned from the hash function `djb2` and `node *` is the node for which the string was built.

Comment: @user763852 That sounds right. If that's still too large, you could try replacing `std::unordered_map` with [another implementation](http://incise.org/hash-table-benchmarks.html). But you would probably gain more by looking into using a different minimization algorithm.